# Preserving file rights when MOVING a folder on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2012

(This question is a variation of 
[Preserving file rights when copying a folder on Windows Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/571475/), only this question is specifically geared towards MOVING files rather than COPYING.)

We have a shared network drive running Windows Server at work.

One of the folders contains sensitive information that should only be visible to a small group of people.

The problem is that if one of those people CUT and paste a folder that has read permissions for everyone into the sensitive folder, anyone will be able to access that folder if they go directly to the full path.

If there any way to set up the file server to make 100% sure that all files and folders created or MOVED anywhere in the tree under x:\sensitive will have the same restricted rights as x:\sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310316

"You can modify how Windows Explorer handles permissions when objects are moved in the same NTFS volume. As mentioned, when an object is moved within the same volume, the object preserves its permissions by default. However, if you want to modify this behavior so that the object inherits the permissions from the parent folder, modify the registry as follows:

```
Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then press ENTER.
Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry value:

Value name: MoveSecurityAttributes
Data type: DWORD
Value data: 0
Exit Registry Editor.
Make sure that the user account that is used to move the object has the Change Permissions permission set. If the permission is not set, grant the Change Permissions permission to the user account.
```

Note The MoveSecurityAttributes registry value only applies to Windows XP and to Windows Server 2003. The value does not affect Windows 2000."